# How can I fix " Object doesn't support this property or method" error when Selecting a shape

Tags: excel, vba

I created 3 speedometers on one sheet `WEstimate`, but when I change information on another sheet (`FCalc`) I get a

> Run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method

I also tried using `Worksheets("WEstimate")` but that would keep sending me to `WEstimate` Sheet whenever I enter info on the `FCalc` Sheet which I don't want. Hope that's enough info.  I have no idea what I'm doing so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("WEstimate").Calculate

    Worksheets("WEstimate").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2394")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = ActiveSheet.Range("W199").Value * 247
    ActiveCell.Select

    Worksheets("WEstimate").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2312")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = ActiveSheet.Range("W200").Value * 247
    ActiveCell.Select

    Worksheets("WEstimate").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2604")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = ActiveSheet.Range("W202").Value * 247
    ActiveCell.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Which sheet module is this code in? "WEstimate" or "FCalc"

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the code is behind sheet `WEstimate`, and some action you take on sheet `FCalc` causes `WEstimate` to recalculate, the cause of your error is that you can't `Select` something on a non-active sheet.  And when `FCalc` is active, `Selection` referes to whatever is selected on `FCalc`.  Classic case of why using `Select` `Selection` or `Active*` is a bad idea.

So, the solution is to refactor to avoid reliance on `Select` `Selection` or `Active*`

Something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True '<~~ Why?
    'Worksheets("WEstimate").Calculate '<~~ This event is triggered by a recalc, so why do it again?

    Dim Speedo As ShapeRange
    Set Speedo = Me.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2394")) '<~~ Can't select something on a non-active sheet
    Speedo.Rotation = Me.Range("W199").Value * 247 '<~~ ActiveSheet may not refer to this sheet
    ' ActiveCell.Select '<~~ not needed now

    Set Speedo = Me.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2312")) 
    Speedo.Rotation = Me.Range("W200").Value * 247 

    Set Speedo = Me.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2604")) 
    Speedo.Rotation = Me.Range("W202").Value * 247 

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, [some general advise on how to avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Comment: Thank you Chris. I had followed another example found on Youtube and tried to mimic it.  I changed True to False, I kept in the recalc as I wanted it to recalc every time I changed a number on the spreadsheet and then changed the remaining programing to what you had shown and that fixed the issue and they are now working perfectly. Thanks again.